# Passing start date for a subscription to PayPal using PayPal Subscribe button?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using PayPal `Subscribe` button in my web app. I would like to pass the subscription start date to PayPal which is not going to be today's date always.

Normally, PayPal will create a subscription that starts from today if no active subscription is there.

**Question:** Is it possible to pass a start date for subscription when using PayPal subscribe button, and if yes, then how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the PayPal subscription buttons then you don't have the option to specify the start date for the profile but in this case you can do some calculations to give trial periods so that profile starts at same time.

In case you are ready to make use of PayPal API's to create the recurring profile then you can specify the start date for your recurring Profile and you have more control on the profiles created .You can refer the below links for more info .

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. It seems that both the links you mentioned will redirect user to PayPal for authorization. Do you know of any way that does not need the user to go to PayPal hosted page?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have direct card recurring payments on your webpage, then you could go for PayPal Payflow PRO. This would require you to first upgrade your PayPal Business account to PRO which involves fees. Also, you need to have SSL certificates for your checkout page.

Once your PayPal account is upgraded to PRO, you could sign up for Payflow account and enable recurring service with Payflow. This method would not require your users to go to PayPal Hosted Page for payments.

Comment: Thanks for the post. PayPal PRO is only available in US, Canada and UK at this time from what I read at this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/. I think I could use Merchant SDK i.e. classical API to do a direct payment using a credit card.